# How to exclude java libraries without using Maven?

Tags: java, spring, jar

I am developing a RESTful web service with Jersey and Spring. I am not allowed to use Maven in my projects and I need to exclude several libraries from jersey-spring3.jar (core, beans, web) in order to utilize those that come with Spring 4, but I don't know how to achieve it without Maven.

Comment: is gradle also banned?

Comment: Yes, due to security policies in my workplace.

Comment: On the face of it that doesn't sound like an entirely sensible policy; what is the reasoning?

Comment: Is because of the firewall, it doesn't allow Maven to conect to the repositories

Comment: That doesn't prevent you from using maven or gradle, it just means you need to manage a local repo of some description, be that on your machine, or a local maven server

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the dependencies from your classpath. jersey-spring3.jar doesn't contain any other dependencies, it contains only the classes for integration of Jersey and Spring, but no other Spring related classes.